# Why does vscode/platformio insist on adding useless entries to my .gitignore file

Tags: visual-studio-code, platformio

I have been using vscode and PlatformIO for a little while now.

I would like my .gitignore file to be:

```
.pioenvs
.piolibdeps
.vscode/
```

but for some reason the IDE insists on adding the following every time I start up:

```
.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json
.vscode/launch.json
```

I am already ignoring the entire .vscode directory, why is it valuable to ignore individual files within that directory?